# cases in equation mode

Tags: equations, cases

I want to  write this equation 
[image]

The curly brace I can't give. I tried this code

```
 \begin{equation}
 \begin{table}
   \begin{tabular}{ll}
    m_i^2  &=\lambda\phi^2_{cl}-\mu^2 \ \mathnormal{acting \ on} 
 \eta^1,....\eta^{N-1}\\
 &=3\lambda\phi^2_{cl}-\mu^2
\tag{11.65}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{equation}
```

It's not working. Giving me this, moreover I am creating a beamer slide. It creates a blank page whenever I write this code.

How can I produce the above result? Plus it is not also numbering my equation.

[image]

Comment: You have to use `cases` environment.

Comment: please explain a bit more detail,can u write it up?

Comment: `table` is a floating environment.  it should never be nested within `equation`.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum,showframe} % just to example
\begin{document}\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation}
  m_i^2 = 
  \begin{cases}
    \lambda\phi^2_{cl}-\mu^2 & \text{acting on $\eta^1,\dots,\eta^{N-1}$;}\\
    3\lambda\phi^2_{cl}-\mu^2 & \text{acting on $\eta^N$.}
  \end{cases}
\tag{11.65}
\end{equation}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{document}
```